# java get particular value from combobox

Tags: java

I'm new to java,so I have not so clear about how to get only `getString("id")` value when button clicked.For now what I get is the id and full name,but what I actually want to get is only id.

```
 jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("id")+" > "+rs.getString("first_name") +" "+ rs.getString("surname"));
```

.
.

```
jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            String value = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();//need to change
            jTextField1.setText(value);
        }
    });
```

[image: I dun want the txtfiel show all the value, I only want to get id]

Comment: What I actual want to show on right hand side is not the full value, I want only the ID,which means 2

Comment: Don't store strings in your combo box. Store objects, having properties. Then get the selected item, and get its ID property. Java is an OO language.

Comment: sorry,I have no idea of how to Store objects and having properties,can you please give me a reference or link?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea of how to Store objects and having properties,can you please give me a reference or link

It is actually not hard to find tutorials and references on the net, for example,

- [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- A  [tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jcombobox-basic-tutorial-and-examples) with an object example

Anyway, here is an example how you could use it:

1. Implement a Java object (let us name it `Person`) which should contains the attributes `id`, `first name and`surname`:

   ```
   public class Person {
       private String id;
       private String firstName;
       private String surname;

       public Person(String id, String fname, String sname) {
           this.id = id;
           this.firstName = fname;
           this.surname = sname;
       }

       public String getId() {
            return id;
       }

       public String getFirstName() {
           return firstName;
       }

       public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
       }

       // toString() method will be called when the ComboBox is rendered
       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return id + " > " + firstName + " " + surname;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add instances of the above object into the ComboBox:

   ```
   jComboBox1.addItem(new Person(rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("surname")));
   ```
3. And modify the action listener as:

   ```
   new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
       Person value = (Person)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
       jTextField1.setText(value.getId());
   }
   ```